# Let f,g be entire functions, with $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)|$ for $|z| > 1,000$ show that $\frac{f}{g}$ is a rational function.

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions, analytic-functions, entire-functions

I had my Ph.D qualifying yesterday and they asked me the following question:

Let $f,g$ be entire functions, with $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)|$ for $|z| > 1,000$.

Show that $\frac{f}{g}$ is a rational function.

I know that both $f,g$ has a power series expansion around any point and with infinite radius because each are entire functions. Also we can have that

$|\displaystyle\frac{f}{g}| \leq 1, \forall$ $|z| > 1,000$.

I know I should use the Schwartz lemma in some way but I can not construct the appropriate function such that $h(0) = 0$. Also how can I use the condition of $|z|> 1,000$? Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: So far, $f = g \equiv 0$ is not ruled out. For $g \neq 0$, note that $f/g$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. What type of singularity has it at $\infty$?

Comment: You mean $\lim_{z\to\infty}$?  since this limit is 0, then it has no singularities at infinity. Then each functions has a finite amount of zeros ? @DanielFischer

Comment: The limit need not be $0$, it could be any complex number with modulus $\leqslant 1$. But, it exists, so the singularity at $\infty$ is removable. And thus $f/g$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$.